# React – Using auth0 user data in class component

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys I really tried a lot of practices but I seem not to figure out how can I import Auth0 data into the component below. What I see as a problem is that I can add Auth0 only to a component with the use of React Hooks. I tried to rewrite my component multiple time for it to support useState and useEffect and all the possible practices I have seen on internet but I seem to not get it just right. Can someone help me out here please?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../firebase.js';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FadeIn from "react-fade-in";
import Placeholder from '../Placeholder/Placeholder.js';
import ClapButton from '../ClapButton/ClapButton.js'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

import { useAuth0 } from "../../react-auth0-spa";

import './Add.css';




class Add extends Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        currentItem: '',
        username: '',
        clapCount: 0,
        items: []
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
      const item = {
        title: this.state.currentItem,
        user: this.props.name,
        clapCount: this.state.clapCount
      }
      itemsRef.push(item);
      this.setState({
        currentItem: '',
        username: '',
        clapCount: 0
      });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 1500);
      });

      const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
      itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let items = snauápshot.val();
        let newState = [];
        for (let item in items) {
          newState.push({
            id: item,
            clapCount: items[item].clapCount,
            title: items[item].title,
            user: items[item].user
          });
        }
        this.setState({
          items: newState
        });
      });
    }

    removeItem(itemId) {
      const itemRef = firebase.database().ref(`/items/${itemId}`);
      itemRef.remove();
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <div className="wrap">
          <Paper variant="outlined" className="add-item">

              <h1>Čauko <span style={{color: '#00A0DD'}}>{this.props.givenName}</span> </h1> 
              <h3>Začni svoj deň s malým prianím.</h3>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-multiline-flexible"
                      label="Tvoje prianie"
                      name="currentItem"
                      variant="filled"
                      multiline
                      rows="6"
                      rowsMax="8"
                      value={this.state.currentItem}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />

                  <Button 
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary">
                    Poslať wish
                  </Button>
              </form>

          </Paper>

          <section className='items-list'>
              <div className="item">
                  <div>
                      {this.state.items.map((item) => {
                          return (
                          <div>
                          {this.state.loading ? (
                            <>
                              <FadeIn>
                              <Placeholder />
                              </FadeIn>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                          <Paper className="wish" key={item.id}>
                              <FadeIn>
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                <div className="name">
                                    <p>poslal <span className="currentName">{item.user}</span></p>
                                    <ClapButton 
                                    wish={item}
                                    clapCount={item.clapCount} />
                                </div>
                              </FadeIn>
                          </Paper>
                          )}
                          </div>
                          )
                      })}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Add
```

I have been generally  trying to put in these lines infront of the class component as well as inside of it to import user data

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const { user, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();
const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components):

"You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components."

Hooks are a fairly new concept in React. They are an alternative to the class lifecycle methods. If you want to use your hook inside your component, you have to refactor it to a function component. In my opinion, React did a really good job on the hook documentation, the [official hook FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-lifecycle-methods-correspond-to-hooks) are really useful for a general guideline on how to approach this.

This is how your class component would look like as a functional component using hooks:

```
function Add({givenName}) {
  // you don't need a constructor anymore, useState hook instead
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [clapCount, setClapCount] = useState(0);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // now you can use the hook as wished
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const { user, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  // useCallback hook to declare functions
  const handleSubmit = useCallback( (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
      const item = {
        title: this.state.currentItem,
        user: this.props.name,
        clapCount: this.state.clapCount
      }
      itemsRef.push(item);
      setCurrentItem('');
      setUsername('');
      setClapCount(0);
  });

   // not in use right now
  const removeItem = useCallback( (itemId) => {
      const itemRef = firebase.database().ref(`/items/${itemId}`);
      itemRef.remove();
  });

  // can be used as a componentDidMount, useEffect hook
  useEffect( () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1500);
    });

    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let items = snauápshot.val();
      let newState = [];
      for (let item in items) {
        newState.push({
          id: item,
          clapCount: items[item].clapCount,
          title: items[item].title,
          user: items[item].user
        });
      }
      setItems(newState);
    });
  }, []);


  return (
      <div className="container">
      <div className="wrap">
          <Paper variant="outlined" className="add-item">

              <h1>Čauko <span style={{color: '#00A0DD'}}>{givenName}</span> </h1> 
              <h3>Začni svoj deň s malým prianím.</h3>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-multiline-flexible"
                      label="Tvoje prianie"
                      name="currentItem"
                      variant="filled"
                      multiline
                      rows="6"
                      rowsMax="8"
                      value={currentItem}
                      onChange={() => setCurrentItem(e.target.value)}
                  />

                  <Button 
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary">
                    Poslať wish
                  </Button>
              </form>

          </Paper>

          <section className='items-list'>
              <div className="item">
                  <div>
                      {items.map((item) => {
                          return (
                          <div>
                          {loading ? (
                            <>
                              <FadeIn>
                              <Placeholder />
                              </FadeIn>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                          <Paper className="wish" key={item.id}>
                              <FadeIn>
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                <div className="name">
                                    <p>poslal <span className="currentName">{item.user}</span></p>
                                    <ClapButton 
                                    wish={item}
                                    clapCount={item.clapCount} />
                                </div>
                              </FadeIn>
                          </Paper>
                          )}
                          </div>
                          )
                      })}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Add
```

Also, be aware that you have quite a lot of unused code. Be sure to not just copy paste my solution but instead read through the code and make sure all variables are declared, used and behave they way you intend them to be used. :)